# When Does High Sierra Reach EOL/EOS?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

I recently confirmed that Apple has dropped support for my mid-2010 MacBook Pro (i.e., I cannot upgrade to Mojave.)

Does anyone know when Apple will drop support for High Sierra? I'd like to know how long I have to come up with a solution before my MBP is exposed to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Best guess, another 3 years. No-one really knows, but they tend to keep updating the last 3 versions. They claim 5 years active, 5 years passive support for any device, so another 3 years would exceed that.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think that'd make a great answer! There's some nice resources which corroborate this, such as https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility

Answer (score 2):

From comments...

Best guess, another 3 years.
No-one really knows, but they tend to keep updating the last 3 versions. They claim 5 years active, 5 years passive support for any device, so another 3 years would exceed that.

MacSales supported OS list would seem to corroborate that - [Mac OS Support Guide](https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You can expect Apple to support High Sierra until **September 2020**.

There is no official end-of-life policy for macOS so this is a guess based on previous history, as September 2020 is when the third macOS version after High Sierra will be released.

> Apple doesn’t have a written policy that guarantees how long it
>   supports each release of macOS with security updates. But you can
>   quickly check to see which versions of macOS Apple is still updating,
>   and they tend to support the most recent three versions.

https://www.howtogeek.com/350901/which-releases-of-macos-are-supported-with-security-updates/